# Get domain join date of Windows Server 2008 (R2) machine?

Tags: com, registry, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a record on a Windows Server 2008 (r2) machine where i can find out when the machine has joined it's domain?

Somewhere in the registry? Or a COM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows logs the event in event log but the event log gets overwritten quickly. you can watch event logs using your own service constantly but that may be slow and ineffective. You can also [turn on AD diagnosis logging on the machine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961809.aspx) and parse netsetup.log.

There's a [whenCreated property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the computer record in AD but that could be wrong if a) the computer record is created in the domain before joining, b) the computer left the domain then rejoined or c) if the data is replicated from another DC. If you have none of these practices, you can use whenCreated as a substitute of the join date.